# Won't allow me to flag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, exact-duplicates

I found an odd problem. I was in newest questions and I saw this:
[image]

Instantly I was going to flag one as duplicate. My problem came when attempting this. The second question wouldn't show up. Any suggestions.

[Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/567339/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line-in-windows-7-and-8)

[Question 2](https://superuser.com/questions/567340/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line-in-windows-7-and-8)

Comment: Could you please clarify, a) you were unable to access both questions and being redirected to one of them, or b) you were unable to enter the other question in the flag/exact duplicate dialog?

Comment: I wasn't able to find it in the flag section

Answer (score 1):

[With the (fairly) recent vote to close changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate), The question needs to be answered for it to show up in the Vote/Flag to Close As Duplicate dialog

> **The search results include only answered questions (per the usual SO definition of "answered", where the question must have an accepted or up-voted answer)**. Additionally, close targets are restricted to answered questions even when specifying the ID or URL directly (with the exception of questions from the same author, and meta posts). Moderators can override this last restriction if necessary.

I've closed the question as dupe now.

Comment: Shouldn't this be covered by the exception? "*with the exception of questions from the same author*"

Comment: @DanielBeck hmm that's true..

Comment: You are only referring to vote to close _as duplicate_, right? It should still be possible to close questions for other reasons.

Comment: @nhinkle yes, that is right